# How import a file (Markdown File) inside public folder in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to 'read' a .MD file inside the public folder (it's need to be in public folder because the user can change these MD files after the build).

File Structure: https://prnt.sc/pg72yq

I think in loading this MD file asynchronously with nodejs or PHP, but i wish load without that, maybe with AJAX, but i actually don't what exactly to do.

```
  /* 
    Reads the page
  */
  read(page){
    let file = require(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `./pages/${page}/index.md`);
    // ... Code
  }
```

Comment: You have tagged `reactjs` so hopping its frontend code, when the file is modified dynamically after the build, then its always good to load via `ajax` or other methods. `require` is resolved at build time and not at resolve time.